# Why lsof -p and just lsof return drastically different results?

Tags: linux, lsof, file-descriptors

I currently have set a open files limit of 100000 but lsof reports that it's close to running out.

Running `lsof -n | awk '{print $2'} | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` results in:

```
      1 PID
  90321 3979
```

Almost the same result is received by `lsof -n | grep 3979 | wc -l`

But running `lsof -n -p 3979 | wc -l` returns something totally different

```
3930
```

Counting the files in `/proc/3979/fd/` also returns the smaller result.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a buggy version of lsof on the loose around the era of this question. This includes ubuntu bionic. The problem with that version of lsof is that it always shows a threaded view and that view can not be turned off..
lsof versions:

- 4.86 (ubuntu trusty) shows process view by default. -K for threaded
- 4.89 (ubuntu bionic) shows threaded view by default. Can't turn it off.
- 4.91 (debian buster) shows threaded view by default. -Ki for process

The /proc filesystem has always been my favourite:

```
ls -d /proc/[1-9]*/fd/*|cut -d/ -f3|sort |uniq -c |sort -rn|head
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the logs from `dropbox` on my system and I see comparable differences.

When I look in detail at the individual logs I find that `dropbox` is shown as having 400 files open with `lsof -p`, and 23500 open with `ls ... | grep '^dropbox'`

Looking at the long list, I find that `dropbox` has 60 threads and most of the base 400 files are reported in each thread, thereby explaining the difference.

What I don't know is whether the file handles in the threads are in shared memory or are individual to the threads. File handles in shared memory should not be counted more than once in the open files limit.

My command to count the threads was:

```
lsof -n | grep "^dropbox " | awk '{print $3}' | uniq | wc -l
```

If your application behaves similarly, then the lower figure is the realistic one.

Note that all the figures are approximate: I have ignored when header lines are included in the counts and the inclusion of the base PID in the thread counts. Since the `ls` reports are from different times, they can never be completely reconciled.